# One JSP file find the CSS external file, But other JSP file can't find the CSS file

Tags: html, css, jsp

Well, I have been working on a J2EE project. But my project behaves strange. I configure spring to handle static resources.

```js
 @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
        
    }
```

I try to access the CSS file from My home.jsp and it works fine. But when I want to access another css file stylerg.css from my another jsp file registration.jsp it is not working!!!!! ??? Same project same structure but the css file behaves carzy. and makes me crazy too. Here is the code of home.jsp

```html
<%-- 
    Document   : home
    Created on : Aug 7, 2018, 4:37:50 PM
    Author     : Noman Ibrahim
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="f" %>

<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="s" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/styleHome.css">
          
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        
        <title>HOME || Doctor's House</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar__header">
                <img src="static/images/doctorlogo.jpg" alt="medical center" class="navbar__logo" >
                <div class="navbar__btn">
                    <div class="bar bar1"></div> 
                    <div class="bar bar2"></div>
                    <div class="bar bar3"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="navbar_link">
                <s:url var="url_log" value="student/loginPage"></s:url>
                <s:url var="url_reg" value="student/Registration"></s:url>
                <s:url var="url_logout" value="student/logout"></s:url>
                <s:url var="url_Doctor_schedule" value="doctor/Schedule"></s:url>
                <s:url var="url_prescription" value="student/prescription"></s:url>


                <li><a href="#" class="navbar_single_link"><i class="fa fa-heartbeat"></i> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="${url_reg}" class="navbar_single_link"><i class="fa fa-hospital-o"></i> Registration</a></li> 
                <li><a href="${url_log}" class="navbar_single_link"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Login</a></li> 
                <li><a href="${url_logout}" class="navbar_single_link"><i class="fa fa-motorcycle"></i> Logout</a></li> 
                <li><a href="${url_Doctor_schedule}" class="navbar_single_link"><i class="fa fa-user-md"></i> Doctor's Schedule</a></li> 
                <li><a href="${url_prescription}" class="navbar_single_link"><i class="fa fa-file"></i> Prescription</a></li> 

            </ul>

        </div>
        <script src="webjars/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <header>
            <h1>MEDICAL CENTER</h1>
            <h2>MAWLANA BHASHANI SCIENCE AND TECHNOLOGY UNIVERSITY</h2>
            <br>
            <br>
            
            <p>Register yourself for claiming the services provided by the medical center<br>You can keep track your prescription from anywhere.<br>It will help you to purchase medicine from any dispensary</p>
        </header>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/main.js">

        </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

and hereis the code of my registration.jsp file.

```html
<%-- 
    Document   : registration
    Created on : Aug 9, 2018, 12:10:46 AM
    Author     : Noman Ibrahim
--%>



<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="f" %>

<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="s" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/stylerg.css">
        
        <title>Student Registration</title>

    </head>


    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <!-- Form Start -->
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="studentId">Your Student ID</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Your Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="address">Current Address</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="dept">Department</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="session">Session</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        
                       
                       
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                    </form>

                    <!-- Form End -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I checked for naming error. There were none. Please any possible solution?

Comment: Perhaps `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">`  this one making you crazy. You can check by commenting bootstrap stylesheet to know whether yours one works or not.

Comment: @ Avijit Barua You know magic. !!! It works now

Comment: Ha ha ha. My pleasure. By the way, if this comment helps you please mark this comment as important.